# Combine import, declare keywords in typescript declaration files

Tags: typescript

Typescript compiler works not as expected when you combine `import` with `declare` statements.

For eg:
we have `class.d.ts` file with content

```
declare class ModuleClass {}
```

and file `main.ts`

```
new ModuleClass()
```

In this scenario typescript transpiles everything without errors.

But if i add `import` statement in `class.d.ts` like that:

```
import * as react from "react"

declare class ModuleClass {}
```

In this case typescript will failed with next error:

```
src/class.ts:1:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ModuleClass'.

1 new ModuleClass()
      ~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

What am i doing wrong? May be i've setup `tsconfig.json` with wrong set of options?

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "js",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "./typings/*",
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the class from `src/class.ts`:

I would set `ModuleClass` as a const and then export it as such:

```
const ModuleClass = { };
export default ModuleClass;
```